# How can I do it with just one Behaviorsubject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have this code:

```
private _fileData$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
private _storageData$: BehaviorSubject<Array<string>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<string>>([]);

    private constructor() {
        this._fileData$.subscribe({ next: (fileData: string) => this._storageData$.next(fileData.toString().split('\r\n')) });
```

So i have some string data in _fileData$ and I want to split it by lines so I get Array of strings, so im creating _storageData$ to put them here.
It works like I want to, but how can I do it using only one BehaviorSubject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private _storageData$: Observable<Array<string>>;

this._storageData$ = this._fileData$
    .pipe(map((fileData) => {
        return fileData.toString().split('\r\n');
    }));
```

Then you can bind to it in your view:

```
<span>{{ _storageData$ | async }}</span>
```

`map` is an [rxjs operator](https://rxjs.dev/guide/operators)

Comment: yess, but I mean is it possible to do it only on _fileData$ without creating new variable _storageData$?

Comment: You probably want to bind to it in the html view, I suppose (`_storageData$ | async`). So if you need it there the answer is no.

Comment: I want to subscribe to it from another component then use it in html, but the answer is same

Comment: Yes, you can do so as well. Be sure to either unsubscribe, or even better use [`.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-video-player/src/lib/components/video-player/video-player.component.ts#L34). As a sidenote, `| async` unsubscribes automatically, but you will need both cases occasionally