# Angular - BehaviorSubject next() call causes problems on logout

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, behaviorsubject

I am working on an Angular project with multi-tenant support. When the user switches to another tenant, other components are notified so they can perform a reload to show the data for the new tenant. This is done by subscribing to a `BehaviorSubject` inside the components which will trigger the reload like this:

```
this.tenantService.currentTenant$.subscribe(() => {
  // Perform reload
});
```

This is how the `BehaviorSubject` looks like in the tenant service:

```
currentTenant$ = new BehaviorSubject<Tenant | undefined>(undefined);
get currentTenant(): Tenant | undefined {
  return this.currentTenant$.value;
}
set currentTenant(value: Tenant | undefined) {
  if (CredentialsService.isEqual(this.currentTenant$.value, value)) {
    return;
  }
  this.currentTenant$.next(value);
}
```

To change the tenant, I can simply set the `currentTenant` to the new tenant. This works just fine in 99% of all cases, but I just found a problem when the user logs out of the application. When the user is logging out, the following function is called:

```
logout() {
  sessionStorage.clear();
  this.currentTenant = undefined;
}
```

When the user has not switched to another tenant, the tenant is already undefined here. Therefore, `currentTenant$.next()` is not called. However, if the user logs out after switching to another tenant, `this.currentTenant = undefined` will trigger a call of `currentTenant$.next()` which will cause all sorts of unwanted behavior in the other components because they try reloading data while the user is trying to log out.

Is there a way how I can "safely" set the current tenant back to `undefined` without triggering a call of `currentTenant$.next()`, or do I have to manually check this in my code (for example with a boolean that is only set to true while a logout is being performed)?

Comment: why not unsubscribing from the service before setting this.currentTenant to undefined?

Comment: @MishaMashina Because it is subscribed to all over the place in many different components. Or can I somehow unsubscribe in all of them at once?

Comment: I am not sure that setting class' var currentTenant will trigger next() on currentTenant$ BehaviorSubject. Are you sure it actually does?

Comment: @MishaMashina Yes, because of `set currentTenant(value: Tenant | undefined)...`.

Comment: To easily unsubscribe you can use [`.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71357352/8941307)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to complete the subject and create a new one. `complete()` will unsubscribe all observers and the subject will not accept new subscriptions. I assume your other components will subscribe to the new subject on init.

```js
logout() {
  sessionStorage.clear();
  this.currentTenant$.complete();
  this.currentTenant$ = new BehaviorSubject<Tenant | undefined>(undefined);
}
```